# How to disable Recovery in Bitlocker

Tags: windows, windows-10, encryption, bitlocker

I dont want to disable or turn off Bitlocker.
Instead I want to disable the recovery key and the option itself.

[image]

I want to hide or disable the two options

1. Press Enter to Continue
2. Press Esc for Bitlocker recovery

If we go to Bitlocker recovery it is allowing access to COmmand prompt in admin mode, I want to get rid of it.

Comment: What you want is not possible.  Even if you were to use a TPM, BitLocker allows provides a Recovery mode, which makes what you want impossible

Comment: What's wrong with the recovery command prompt? Isn't virtually everything still encrypted anyway?

Comment: I want to hide/disable these options, I don't want to recover if password is lost. Further it is allowing me to navigate to cmd in admin from advanced options.